# Hilbert operator that maintains the norm

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

What are the required properties of a Hilbert space operator to maintain the norm when applied to a vector? For example if $\| |u\rangle \| = 1$ and $A\, |u\rangle = |v\rangle$, what are the properties of $A$ to ensure $\| |v\rangle \| = 1$?

A normal operator is enough ($A^\dagger A=AA^\dagger$) or needs to be a unitary operator ($A^\dagger A=I$)? Or other?

Comment: this is not an isometry (a linear operator that maintain the norm)?

Comment: Thanks Masacroso. I believe so, I come from the field of Quantum Computing, so I am basically interested in finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces. I believe in that case all isometric operators are unitary operators. Do you know if that is true?

Comment: Yes, the operator must be unitary. Just check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_operator for the distinction between finite and infinite-dimensional.